# Jquery flightboard flip in table

Tags: php, jquery, html, xml

I have a PHP function that is reading data from an XML file and creating a table. Everytime the XML file gets updated, the new information is displayed.

Hoping to use JQuery to add some pizazz. I'd like to use the following flightboard plugin:

```
http://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Airport-Flight-Board-Text-Effect-with-jQuery-flightboard.html
```

To be able flip the text only in the price column of my fiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/Ahsatan/n6vxjskq/
```

How do I go about doing this?

Currently, my JQuery uses the ajax function to retrieve an HTML string (the table with its contents) from the PHP function.

Any help is deeply appreciated. :-)

Comment: Did you tried to use that plugin? And what is problem?

Comment: The only way I could think of using it, is to parse the giant HTML string to grab the prices and then call the function on each price. It doesn't work and the whole process seems like a very inefficient way of doing this.